# Multiple OnClick events not working on all objects

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have made a basic android layout with frames holding and image and a textview in each.

The issue I am having is the OnClick event only seems to work on the first two. I have re-read my code and can not fathom why it does not work for all the framelayouts...

I am very new to Android so I may have missed something obvious.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tempframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sunimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sun" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temptext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/himidityframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dropimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/waterdrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/humiditytext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/windframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/windimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/wind" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/windtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/clockframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clockimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/stationclockl" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clocktext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/voltageframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/voltageimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/battery" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/voltagetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/deviceframe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:clickable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/deviceimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/weatherstation1cinverted" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/devicetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </FrameLayout>
</GridLayout>`
```

The applicable piece of java/activity code:

```
public class Current extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_current);

    FrameLayout tempframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.tempframe);
    FrameLayout humidityframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.himidityframe);
    FrameLayout windframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.windframe);
    FrameLayout clockframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.clockframe);
    FrameLayout voltageframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.voltageframe);
    FrameLayout deviceframe = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.deviceframe);

    final TextView temptext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temptext);
    final TextView humiditytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humiditytext);
    final TextView windtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windtext);
    final TextView clocktext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clocktext);
    final TextView voltagetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voltagetext);
    final TextView devicetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.devicetext);

    tempframe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Current.this, "Temperature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    humidityframe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Current.this, "Humidity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    windframe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Current.this, "Wind Speed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    clockframe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Current.this, "Clock/Time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    voltageframe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Current.this, "Voltage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    deviceframe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(Current.this, "Devices and Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please use LinearLayouts instead of FrameLayouts. FrameLayouts are only for one single child element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:clickable=true` from ImageView and TextView.

ImageView/TextView is on top of FrameLayout, so if you set `android:clickable=true` to these children, those are interfering the click listener and not delegated to parent (FrameLayout).

In fact, you can remove `clickable` property everywhere in this xml, `setOnClickListener` automatically makes clickable to true on the view.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I did not know that parents can have their properties overridden by children. I will have a look at setClickListener. I assume that is some form of "global" listener that can then fetch IDs like in some form of "if case" scenario making my coding a lot less busy.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this?  "global" listener and fetch ID
https://uwudamith.wordpress.com/2012/05/19/how-to-use-onclicklistener-in-android/

This is an old post but you'll see an idea. `setOnClickListener(this)` and `OnClick` function.